# Redux + reactflow add edges through a reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

Hi I'm still new to redux and I'm trying to manipulate the nodes in [reactflow](https://reactflow.dev/docs/getting-started/) library using redux, I've managed to add a node through a reducer but when I try to add an edge(the link between nodes) it returns a warning
can anyone helps me with how to handle it in reducer

**Link to sandbox if you want to see the code**
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-flow-add-node-button-with-redux-1q2dz?file=/src/store/reducer.js

[warning image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RC5f.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is more a `react-flow` question than it is a redux question but the issue is that you aren't dispatching an action with the source and target node ids you want to connect.

App: dispatch the add edge action with the vertices/node ids you want to connect:

```
const AddEdge = ({ source, target }) => {
  dispatch({
    type: "ADD_EDGE",
    source,
    target,
  });
};
```

Reducer - don't mutate the state object, just ***return a new*** state object value:

```
export const reducer = (state = initialElements, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_NODE:
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          id: Math.random().toString(),
          position: { x: 100, y: 50 },
          data: { label: "yo" }
        }
      ];
    case ADD_EDGE:
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          id: Math.random().toString(),
          source: action.source,
          target: action.target
        }
      ];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

[image: Edit react-flow-add-node-button -with-redux (forked)]